# Question on standard filtration Ex 3.7(a) James Humphreys "Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category O"

Tags: lie-algebras

**Exercise 3.7(a) James Humphreys's "Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category O"**

Let $V \in \mathcal{O}$ be a module which admits a standard filtration. Suppose that there is a surjective homomorphism $$\phi: V \rightarrow  M(\mu)$$ where $M(\mu)$ is a Verma module. Show that ker$\phi$ also admits a standard filtration.

My attempt: Suppose that $\lambda$ is maximal among the weights of $V$ and let $M(\lambda)$ be the corresponding submodule.

If $\mu \neq \lambda$, then the composition of the embedding $ M(\lambda) \rightarrow V$ and $ \phi: V \rightarrow  M(\mu)$ yields the composition $$M(\lambda) \rightarrow V \rightarrow M(\mu)$$ which is $0$ by the maximality assumption of $\lambda$. Hence, we have the surjection $$V/M(\lambda) \rightarrow  M(\mu)$$ and since the quotient module $V/M(\lambda)$ also admits a standard filtration (I am guessing we can argue by induction on the length of $V$ but I am a bit confused about this. Can anyone show me this?).

Furthermore, if $\mu = \lambda$, then $\operatorname{ker} \phi \cong V/M(\lambda)$ (is my claim true? why is this so?) $\operatorname{ker} \phi$ admits a standard filtration since $V/M(\lambda)$ has a standard filtration.

Comment: To clarify, my exercise was meant to use the preceding proposition.        These ideas evolved after the 1970s work of BGG, especially in papers by Ron Irving; for a more traditional account you might track down the 2005 lecture notes by Dennis Gaitsgory (which he used to keep on his webpage):  see his section 4.3.    Irving's arguments streamline the proofs of basic facts such as BGG reciprocity, so my organization differs from Gaitsgory's.    [By the way, a tag such as rt.representation-theory should probably be added.]

Answer (score 1):

This will go much smoother if you say: we can assume that our standard filtration is chosen so that the weights are non-decreasing.  That is, $\{0\}\subset V_1\subset V_2\subset \cdots \subset V$ satisfies $V_{i}/V_{i-1}\cong M(\lambda_i)$ with $\lambda_i> \lambda_j$ implies $i<j$.  (This is because unless $\lambda_i>\lambda_{i+1}$, we have $V_{i+1}/V_{i-1}\cong M(\lambda_i)\oplus M(\lambda_{i+1})$, so we can rearrange the filtration to reorder these weights.)  I assume this is proven somewhere in Humphreys.  Arguments with standard filtrations tend to work much better once you make sure they are in this form.

Let $k$ be maximal such that $V_k$ is killed by the map to $M(\mu)$.  Then, we have a surjective map $V/V_k\to M(\mu)$.  Since the map $V_{k+1}/V_k\to M(\mu)$ isn't zero, we must have $\lambda_{k+1}\leq \mu$.  If $\lambda_{k+1} <\mu$, then the map $V_{k+1}/V_k\to M(\mu)$ isn't surjective, and so $\mu$ must appear as a weight of $M(\lambda_m)$ for $m>k+1$.  This is impossible, since $\lambda_m\geq \mu>\lambda_{k+1}$ implies $m<k+1$.  Thus, we must have $\lambda_{k+1}=\mu$, and $V_{k+1}/V_{k}\to M(\mu)$ is an isomorphism.

Thus, the quotients $(V_{m}\cap\ker \phi)/(V_{m-1}\cap\ker\phi)\cong V(\lambda_m)$ as long as $m\neq k+1$, and is 0 when $m=k+1$.  Thus, these intersections $V_{m}\cap\ker \phi$ give the desired filtration.